# Percent with SUM of a SUM in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Cheers.

I need to calculate wich percet of the total salaries gets every department in a chosen year.

```
SELECT D.dept_name AS 'Department', SUM(S.salary) AS 'Total', CONCAT(ROUND(SUM(SUM(S.salary)), 2), '%') AS '%'
FROM departments D INNER JOIN dept_emp DE ON D.dept_no=DE.dept_no INNER JOIN  salaries S ON DE.emp_no=S.emp_no
WHERE (S.from_date<='2000-01-01') AND (S.to_date>='2000-12-31')
GROUP BY D.dept_name
```

I tried that but it doesnt work; it says: 
Error code 1111, SQL state HY000: Invalid use of group function

The SUM(SUM()) sounds very suspicious to me, but I'm out of ideas.

Here are the tables if you need:

```
REATE TABLE employees (
    emp_no      INT             NOT NULL,
    birth_date  DATE            NOT NULL,
    first_name  VARCHAR(14)     NOT NULL,
    last_name   VARCHAR(16)     NOT NULL,
    gender      ENUM ('M','F')  NOT NULL,    
    hire_date   DATE            NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_no)
);

CREATE TABLE departments (
    dept_no     CHAR(4)         NOT NULL,
    dept_name   VARCHAR(40)     NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (dept_no),
    UNIQUE  KEY (dept_name)
);

CREATE TABLE dept_emp (
    emp_no      INT             NOT NULL,
    dept_no     CHAR(4)         NOT NULL,
    from_date   DATE            NOT NULL,
    to_date     DATE            NOT NULL,
    KEY         (emp_no),
    KEY         (dept_no),
    FOREIGN KEY (emp_no)  REFERENCES employees   (emp_no)  ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (dept_no) REFERENCES departments (dept_no) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_no,dept_no)
);

CREATE TABLE salaries (
    emp_no      INT             NOT NULL,
    salary      INT             NOT NULL,
    from_date   DATE            NOT NULL,
    to_date     DATE            NOT NULL,
    KEY         (emp_no),
    FOREIGN KEY (emp_no) REFERENCES employees (emp_no) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_no, from_date)
);
```

Comment: You're rightly suspicious. Give us proper DDLs and a desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

I've done a couple of modifications to the @Spencer7593 solution:

```
SELECT D.dept_name                           AS `Department`
     , SUM(S.salary)                         AS `Total`
     , MAX(t.tot)                            AS `total_all_departments`
     , ROUND((SUM(S.salary)/MAX(t.tot)))*100 AS `pct`
  FROM departments D
  JOIN dept_emp    DE ON DE.dept_no = D.dept_no
  JOIN salaries    S  ON S.emp_no = DE.emp_no
 CROSS
  JOIN ( 
         SELECT SUM(ts.salary) AS `tot`
           FROM departments td
           JOIN dept_emp    te ON td.dept_no = te.dept_no
           JOIN salaries    ts ON te.emp_no=ts.emp_no
           WHERE ts.from_date <= '2000-01-01'
           AND ts.to_date   >= '2000-12-31'
       ) t
 WHERE S.from_date <= '2000-01-01'
   AND S.to_date   >= '2000-12-31'
 GROUP BY D.dept_name
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches to getting the specified result.

One approach is to use an inline view to get the total salary for all departments. For example, a query like this:

```
  SELECT SUM(ts.salary) AS `tot`
    FROM departments td
    JOIN dept_emp    te ON td.dept_no = te.dept_no
    JOIN salaries    ts ON te.emp_no=ts.emp_no
```

You can reference the result from that query in another query, by wrapping it parens and including it in place of table name. The inline view has to be assigned an alias. (In the MySQL venacular, this is referred to as a "derived table".)

For example:

```
SELECT D.dept_name                           AS `Department`
     , SUM(S.salary)                         AS `Total`
     , MAX(t.tot)                            AS `total_all_departments`
     , ROUND(SUM(S.salary)/MAX(t.tot)*100,0) AS `pct`
  FROM departments D
  JOIN dept_emp    DE ON DE.dept_no = D.dept_no
  JOIN salaries    S  ON S.emp_no = DE.emp_no
 CROSS
  JOIN ( 
         SELECT SUM(ts.salary) AS `tot`
           FROM departments td
           JOIN dept_emp    te ON td.dept_no = te.dept_no
           JOIN salaries    ts ON te.emp_no=ts.emp_no
       ) t
 WHERE S.from_date <= '2000-01-01'
   AND S.to_date   >= '2000-12-31'
 GROUP BY D.dept_name
```

---

This isn't the only approach. For example, you could also use a subquery in the SELECT list. There's other approaches that can work, but some of those rely on having a unique identifier for rows in some tables. We'd need some table definitions before we demonstrate those.

Comment: I see what you did and it's a great way to calculate the total but, fore some reason pct is always 0 ><

Comment: It might be the expression that does the calculation. Make sure the two expressions that return total salary "for each department" and "for all departments" are returning correct values.  Next step would be add an expression that does the division of the two (to get a fraction). Once you get that, work on modifying the expression to get the rounding and formatting.